# How to Make an entire table cell act as a clickable form area

Tags: php, css, html

I have a table with a cell that I want everything within it to be clickable
I need the data within the cell to POST data via a form

```
<td  BGCOLOR="#77777" align="center" valign="center">
<form method="post" action="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=11"  name="details">
<input type="hidden" id="UUID" name="UUID" value="<?php echo $dealUUID?>">
<input type="image"  height="300" width="365" src="php_scripts/getdealimage.php?id='<?php echo $dealUUID?>'" name="checked" value="<?php echo $info[0]; ?>">
</form>
<div id="dealdata">
<br /><?echo $dealpromo;?> 
<h1><?echo $dealvalue; ?></h1>
</div> 
</td>
```

so I would like the entire  area to be a clickable area and SEND the form data

Comment: Look over to the right under "Related" >>>

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have been trying - but nothing seems relevant? Hence why I placed this as a new question?

Answer (score 0):

To submit the table cell u can use this

```
$('td > form').each(function(i,e){
   var form = $(this);
   var cell = form.parent();
   if(cell.is('td')){
     cell.click(function(){
       form.submit();
     });
   }
});
```

If you jsut want to follow the link instead, jsut modify the form.submit() part to change window.location.href with form.attr('action').